# xerces c++ getChildNodes getLength

Tags: c++, xerces

I am trying to parse am XML string using xerces c++.

The structure is

```
<root>
<optionA>
<optionB/>
</optionA>
</root>
```

I read the xml string into MemBufInputSource and then parse it.

When I call getChildNodes() on root, it always returns 2. Should it not be 1? Here, only option A is the child of root. Also, for each child I check if its a node and of type element. For the first child, the check is always false.

Why does it show a count of 2 children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getChildNodes()` returns all child nodes, not just the ones that are elements.

The whitespace between the elements (new lines in this case) count as a text node (`DOMNode::NodeType::TEXT_NODE`). By my count there are actually 2 text nodes in your example, so 3 child nodes overall, though differences when transcribing into the question, or different configuration of Xerces may have resulted in 2 child nodes in your original code.

If you change your XML example to be all on one line with no whitespace

`<root><optionA><optionB/></optionA></root>`

you can see that Xerces will then report that there is only one child of `root`.

Here is the [full list of node types](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMNode.html#6237ede96be83ff729807688e4f638c5) that Xerces may encounter.